# Running a bilge pump from a wall outlet?

Tags: electrical, pump, electric-motor

I bought a bilge pump for purposes of cooling off my computer, and to my surprise it came with bare wires (one black and one brown) that you're supposed to hook up to a boat.  I don't own a boat, and until I started this project I didn't really know this is what a bilge pump was for.  I'll be pumping hot air and not water.

The pump says that it runs on 1.8 Amps @ 13.6 VDC; of course I'm going to have to find a way to convert it from my plug to direct current (if that's what VDC stands for...) would it be possible to use a computer power supply or something to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps you are just not cut out for computer modding. In any case, this is not home improvement, and you don't pump air with a water pump.

Comment: -1 If this is a serious question you shouldn't be modding anything.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cooling a computer. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, this is to water-cool the laptop.  My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bilge pumps can only pump water. They cannot be used to pump air. If they are run "dry", they will be damaged.

As for the power supply, a PC power supply normally has a +12 V output. This is likely close enough to 13.6V for the pump to work (when pumping water).

A laptop, or a PC power supply is not rated for enough current, you will need to buy an external DC supply. Make sure that it is rated to supply at least 1.8 amps, though somewhat higher is best. I would suggest a supply rated at between 2.5 and 4 amps.

Answer (score 0):

What in the world made you think you could use a bilge pump to pump air to cool a computer???? There are SO many other proper options out there.

A few additional muffin fans would do a MUCH better job, and you can find them that plug right into the computer harness. Even those that pop into drive slots in the back of the case/motherboard.

Comment: It's from a DIY project in Popular Science's "The Big Book of Hacks" hack 181 "Build a Laptop Cooling System".

Comment: It's similar to this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-removable-laptop-water-cooler!-And-other-co/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: You do realize they are talking about circulating water, don't you?

Comment: I didn't at first, I've never owned a boat, I just saw it on the parts list.  I'm not real big into fishing, just computers.

Comment: No, I meant the laptop cooler.